# How to set the maximum available "refresh rate" (Not target frame rate) for mobile device?

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-development

I have set application.targetframrate = 60.

When I built the apk and installed it in other devices, it worked well with full fps.

But for my device it lowered the fps.

I figured out that my device "refresh rate" was set to 60 Hz. So I changed it to 90 Hz(max) in my Android and now it works well.

But all users may not have their refresh rate set to max.

Is there any way to set the refresh rate to the max available for the device?

Answer (score 0):

```
Application.targetFrameRate = Mathf.Max(60, Screen.currentResolution.refreshRate);
```

This line should give you what you are looking forward, but pay attention it won't handle lower than 60, so I would say either you enable vsync1, for lower end devices.